# Saving spark dataframe from azure databricks' notebook job to azure blob storage causes java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: databricks, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I have created a simple job using notebook in azure databricks.
I am trying to save a spark dataframe from notebook to azure blob storage.
Attaching the sample code

```py
import traceback

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

# Attached the spark submit command used
# spark-submit --master local[1] --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:2.7.2,
# com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:3.1.0 ./write_to_blob_from_spark.py

# Tried with com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:2.2.0

SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "xxxxx"
STORAGE_NAME = "my_storage"
CONTAINER = "my_container"
SUB_PATH = "/azure_dbs_check/"
FILE_NAME = "result"

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("azure_dbs_to_azure_blob") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(["10", "11", "13"], StringType()).toDF("age")
df.show()

try:
    spark_context = spark.sparkContext
    fs_acc_key = "fs.azure.account.key." + STORAGE_NAME + ".blob.core.windows.net"

    spark.conf.set("fs.wasbs.impl",
                   "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
    spark.conf.set(fs_acc_key, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

    file_path = 'wasbs://' + CONTAINER + '@' + STORAGE_NAME + '.blob.core.windows.net' + SUB_PATH + FILE_NAME

    df.write.save(file_path + '_csv', format='csv', header=True, mode="overwrite")
    print("Written successful")
except Exception as exp:
    print("Exception occurred")
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

The above code works when i run the spark-submit in local machine.
The spark submit command used is

> spark-submit --master local[1] --packages
>   org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:2.7.2,com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:3.1.0
>   ./write_to_blob_from_spark.py

The probable root cause might be

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
>   com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopyFromBlob

So i downgraded the package to *com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:2.2.0* which contains the *startCopyFromBlob* method.
 (In com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:3.x.x versions,this ***deprecated startCopyFromBlob()*** on CloudBlob is removed)

Error remains the same even after downgrading process.

Attaching the error stack trace,

```py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<command-4281470986294005>", line 28, in <module>
        df.write.save(file_path + '_csv', format='csv', header=True, mode="overwrite")
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 738, in save
        self._jwrite.save(path)
      File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
        answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
        return f(*a, **kw)
      File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
        format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o255.save.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:240)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:292)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 7.0 (TID 52, 10.2.3.12, executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1526)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error closing the output.
        at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:880)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityGenerator.close(UnivocityGenerator.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.close(CSVFileFormat.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseResources(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:242)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1560)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:248)
        ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopyFromBlob(Ljava/net/URI;Lcom/microsoft/azure/storage/AccessCondition;Lcom/microsoft/azure/storage/AccessCondition;Lcom/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/BlobRequestOptions;Lcom/microsoft/azure/storage/OperationContext;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.StorageInterfaceImpl$CloudBlobWrapperImpl.startCopyFromBlob(StorageInterfaceImpl.java:399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2372)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$NativeAzureFsOutputStream.restoreKey(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:918)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$NativeAzureFsOutputStream.close(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:819)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:320)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
        at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:876)
        ... 19 more

    Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2355)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2343)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2342)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2342)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2574)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2522)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2510)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2243)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:167)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1526)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error closing the output.
        at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:880)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityGenerator.close(UnivocityGenerator.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.close(CSVFileFormat.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseResources(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:242)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1560)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:248)
        ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopyFromBlob(Ljava/net/URI;Lcom/microsoft/azure/storage/AccessCondition;Lcom/microsoft/azure/storage/AccessCondition;Lcom/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/BlobRequestOptions;Lcom/microsoft/azure/storage/OperationContext;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.StorageInterfaceImpl$CloudBlobWrapperImpl.startCopyFromBlob(StorageInterfaceImpl.java:399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2372)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$NativeAzureFsOutputStream.restoreKey(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:918)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$NativeAzureFsOutputStream.close(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:819)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:320)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
        at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:876)
        ... 19 more
```

Included Spark submit packages:

- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:2.7.2,
- com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:3.1.0 (later tried with *com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:2.2.0*)

**Local machine:**
Python 3.6
Spark version 2.4.4 Using Scala version 2.11.12

**Databricks details:**
Cluster information:
5.5 LTS (includes Apache Spark 2.4.3, Scala 2.11)
Python 3 (3.5)

The [Runtime 5.5 release notes](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/5.5.html) says that the package ***com.microsoft.azure azure-storage   5.2.0*** is already installed in the environment.

Is the problem due to spark taking the library from environment(*5.2.0 version*) even though another version(*2.2.0*) is specified in job?
In versions like 5.2.0,the method *startCopyFromBlob()* is [removed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3253d26d-cf7f-46ec-82a2-7ac71e96daf6/upload-to-azure-blob-with-hadoop-fs-command-fails?forum=windowsazuredata).

I have documented the various cases/combinations of jars that i have tried in the [google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LtIqWzhmXxZ4_OQoqIwvSdL3m8ykhHuWKv9HieEjlP0/edit?usp=sharing)

**Observations:**

1. Databricks Job uses pre-installed library azure-storage:5.2.0. This package does not have  *com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopyFromBlob()* method. (replaced by startCopy() in 4.x.x versions). azure-storage is fixed as 5.2.0
2. So i tried to use latest hadoop-azure:3.2.1 in an attempt to get jar which does not call the deprecated method. But this caused a new error 
   *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StreamCapabilities* .
3. StreamCapabilities class is present in hadoop-common packages. So i included latest hadoop-common (3.2.1). 
   This caused
   *java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.ProviderUtils.excludeIncompatibleCredentialProviders()*. 
   **Reason**:
    *org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.3* is pre-installed on azure run time. This hadoop-common:2.7.3 does not have *ProviderUtils.excludeIncompatibleCredentialProviders()* method.
4. Since both packages(hadoop-common:2.7.3 & azure-storage:5.2.0) are fixed(pre-installed), i tried to use the lower hadoop-azure packages in an attempt to find version which does not call *excludeIncompatibleCredentialProviders()* method.
5. From *hadoop-azure:3.2.1(latest as of Nov 2019)* to *hadoop-azure:2.8.0*, *excludeIncompatibleCredentialProviders()* is called inside.
   **Below 2.8.0**, am started to get the old error 
   **NoSuchMethodError: com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopyFromBlob**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative is to create a mount:

https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html

And then adjust the save path as necessary.

---

Also I'd recommend using this

```
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  "<storage-account-access-key>")
```

Instead of

```
spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(fs_acc_key, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

Since you are using the DataFrame api instead of the RDD api.

---

Edit

Ran the following code in a Databricks Community cluster and modified the spark.conf.set statements.

```
import traceback

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

# Attached the spark submit command used
# spark-submit --master local[1] --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:2.7.2,
# com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:3.1.0 ./write_to_blob_from_spark.py

# Tried with com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:2.2.0

SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "ACCESSKEY"
STORAGE_NAME = "ACCOUNTNAME"
CONTAINER = "CONTAINER"
SUB_PATH = "/azure_dbs_check/"
FILE_NAME = "result"

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("azure_dbs_to_azure_blob") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(["10", "11", "13"], StringType()).toDF("age")
df.show()

try:
    fs_acc_key = "fs.azure.account.key." + STORAGE_NAME + ".blob.core.windows.net"

    spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.wasb.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
    spark.conf.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
    spark.conf.set(fs_acc_key, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

    file_path = 'wasbs://' + CONTAINER + '@' + STORAGE_NAME + '.blob.core.windows.net' + SUB_PATH + FILE_NAME

    print(file_path)

    df.write.save(file_path + '_csv', format='csv', header=True, mode="overwrite")

    print("Written successful")
except Exception as exp:
    print("Exception occurred")
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

[image: Databricks cmd output]

[image: Azure Storage Account]

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Updated the configuration setting to **spark.conf.set()** . I am trying to write to azure without mounting it on dbfs.

Comment: All right. Let me try to reproduce it, give me a few minutes.

Comment: It works @Carlos . Just wanted to know which version of library is searching for key _spark.hadoop.fs.wasb.impl_ instead of _fs.wasb.impl_. When i see the [source code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java) for (hadoop-common:2.7.3 mentioned in [5.5 release notes](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/5.5.html) ) , i could see only the "fs.{}.impl".format(schema). Line No: 2577
If i know the exact jar&version which causes the *key change*, i will use the same in local machine too